# How do i refer to methods inside a UIVIiw?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I have imported my .h file into a 2nd one, but in the 2nd one i'm trying to do:

```
FirstClass *firstClass = [FirstClass alloc] init];
[firstClass iconWithType:test];
```

To match this:

```
-(void)iconWithType:(NSString *)iconType
```

But it's not listing iconWithType as a suggestion and i get a warning saying it might not respond to that.

How can i get this to work properly?

My FirstClass is a UIView.

Comment: Have you declared the method in your .h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your FirstClass.h file do you have the method definition in the `interface`?

I.e.

```
@interface FirstClass : NSObject {
}

- (void)iconWithType:(NSString *)iconType;

@end
```

Additionally, the name of the method implies something should be returned. However, it is marked as void.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just have a return type mismatch. Take a look: does `-iconWithType:` actually return `void`? or does it return a `UIImage` or something else besides?